# Pimenton ahumado vs. Pimenton de la vera

Tags: spices, spanish-cuisine, paprika

Besides the noticeable cost difference between these two, what is the difference between *pimenton ahumado* and *pimenton de la vera*? Both are purported to be Spanish smoked paprika.

Comment: Why the upper case in "Pimenton"? It should be in "La Vera", which is the name of a place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the best I can tell, "de la vera" is a regional form of spanish smoked paprika, where ahumado is the more generic form. Sort of like how real cheddar cheese only comes from Cheddar, England or or a true Burgundy wine can only come from Burgundy, France - "de la vera" comes from around the Tietar River in La Vera, Spain.

> Pimenton de la Vera has been protected
>   by a certified designation of origin
>   since 1998 in order to provide you,
>   the end consumer, with a guarantee
>   that you really are getting the best.
>   The government managed regulating
>   council for Pimenton de la Vera
>   carefully monitors all steps of
>   growing, harvest, and production to
>   ensure the strictest quality standards
>   are met. No simple pepper can meet
>   these standards, only those who follow
>   the time-honored traditions exactly.
>   Although there are many other
>   paprika’s in the world, including
>   other certified origin products such
>   as our Pimenton from Murcia, only
>   those grown and smoked in the La Vera
>   valley may bear the certification.

[source](http://www.hotpaella.com/Traditions-Of-Spain-Pimenton-De-La-Vera.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Briefly:

- "pimentón" is Spanish for "paprika".
- "ahumado" is Spanish for "smoked". There is non-smoked pimentón as well, so "pimentón ahumado" is just one of the varieties of pimentón. Others are "dulce" ("sweet", meaning not hot) and "picante" ("hot").
- "de La Vera" means "from La Vera" which, as Ryan says, is a region in Spain where they make one of the best-known smoked paprikas in Spain.

So, "pimentón ahumado" is a generic, very much like "red wine", whereas "pimentón de La Vera" is a specific provenance product, like "Rioja" or "Barossa Valley".