# What type of Paprika is the generic stuff one buys at a grocery store chain?

Tags: spices, shopping, spanish-cuisine, paprika

I have read [this very good link](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2938/what-are-the-differences-between-various-types-of-paprika-and-which-have-the-mo) on the differences in paprika, but I did not learn all that I need to learn as far as buying these different varieties.  When I go to my grocery chain to do my weekly shopping and I see the spice container which says Paprika, is that just going to be "Plain" paprika.  I ask because I need to go out and find both sweet paprika and hot paprika which probably will require a little more effort on my part to find.  Maybe a Whole Foods or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information should be indicated on the label: sweet, sweet&sour, spicy, smoked...

Generic paprika is sweet and will probably not have much flavor (that is why paprika can be used in paella together with saffron - see [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17755/whats-in-a-paella))

Comment: This might be accidentally US/western centric - are we sure that "generic paprika" will not get you something surprisingly spicy (eg deggi mirch or even cayenne powder) in some english speaking locales? Not a rhetorical question.

Comment: @rackandboneman : I suspect that if you were in a grocery store in Spain or Hungary the answers would be different from that in the US.  Other places in the EU, I have no clue.